# how to break a loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

```
when 1
    add(first_number, second_number)

    begin 
    print "Calculate again? [y/n]: "
    response = gets.chomp

    if response.downcase =~ /[n]/
        break

    elsif response.downcase =~ /[^ny]/
        puts "please input y or n"

    else response.downcase =~ /[y]/
        puts "yay"
    end 
end
```

**EDIT**

Profuse apologies. This is a changed version.

My question as it stands now is how do I keep repeating the question of 'please input y or n' when a user chooses to enter other than those characters?

Comment: `when 1` will raise a syntax error.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, no, I just didn't include the whole code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, in other words, please ignore that. I just want the darn loop to break when a user enters a 'n'.

Comment: You need a loop that continues until `'n'` is entered. `break if response == 'n'` will then get you out of the loop. Each time something other than `'n'` is entered, repeat the calculation if `'y'` is entered.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I just edited my post above. Hope it's ok. Any insights? Please and thank you.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543 : for your reference I have provided one link to my answer...it will helps u

Answer (score 4):

the `begin <code> end while <condition>` is regretted by Ruby's author **[Matz](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745)**. Instead, he suggests to use `Kernel#loop`,

**e.g.**
The `while` statement modifier normally checks the condition `before` entering the loop. But **if** the `while` statement modifier is on a `begin ... end` statement, then it loops at least once. Same with the `until` statement modifier.

Example of **while**

```
val = 0
begin
   val += 1
   puts val
end while val % 6 != 0
```

Example of **until**

```
val = 0
begin
   val += 1
   puts val
end until val % 6 == 0
```

As you wants to know about `breaks`..

Example of **break unless**

```
val = 0
loop do
   val += 1
   puts val
   break unless val %6 != 0
end
```

Example of  **break if**

```
val = 0
loop do
   val += 1
   puts val
   break if val %6 == 0
end
```

### Output:

Above all four of these examples print the numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

I hope this answer makes you clear..

For your reference I have found very nice Example of Code about **[Table of Contents](https://gist.github.com/EForester/3956165)**  You can Execute(Run) that code **[here online](http://repl.it/languages/Ruby)** and check the result. If my answer somehow helps you then you can accept as answered. :)

Comment: Gagan, imo you should not attribute an opinion to an individual (here Matz) without providing a reference.

Comment: @CarySwoveland :  Thanks for your opinion.. I have updated reference (here Matz)

Comment: Good, and interesting brief discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably extract the confirmation into a method, something like:

```
def confirm(message)
  loop do
    print "#{message} [y/n]: "
    case gets.chomp
    when 'y', 'Y' then
      return true
    when 'n', 'N'
      return false
    else
      puts 'please input y or n'
    end
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
loop do
  puts 'Calculating...'
  sleep 5 # calculation
  puts '42'
  break unless confirm('Calculate again?')
end
```

Usage:

```
$ ruby test.rb
Calculating...
42
Calculate again? [y/n]: maybe
please input y or n
Calculate again? [y/n]: y
Calculating...
42
Calculate again? [y/n]: n
$
```

Comment: Good to see you separating the loop to get a valid response from the calculate-again loop.  I'd be inclined to delete `else` and move `puts 'please input y or n'` to after `end`, but that's a stylistic issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your loopy method in a separate thread, and then
kill that thread when the user presses any key on the keyboard ...